# Getting Wifi SSID in Android13/API Level 33

Tags: android, wifimanager

Whrn i try to get the WIFI-SSID, I get UNKNOWN_SSID

below is my Code:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.super.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.super.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Network netnow = cm.getActiveNetwork();
        WifiInfo wf =  (WifiInfo)cm.getNetworkCapabilities(netnow).getTransportInfo();
        String ssid = wf.getSSID();
    }
}
```

i want to get the right SSID.
The document said WIFIinfo requires same permission as WifiManager#getScanResults,I checked it but still cant get ssid,i dont know why and how can i solve it.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmiTf.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaifC.png)

Comment: You need location permissions to get ssid. Already since Android 11 i think.

Comment: I add it in AndroidManifest.xml and try to check it as u can see in the code.

Comment: Yes i see you try to get fine location -in the wrong way by the way-. But you did not tell if you got permission. Nor did you tell if it worked for you.

Comment: Sry,i'm not very familiar with Android, i just test it on my own device and grant the location permission. So what's the right way to get finelocation.

Comment: You did not tell if that worked for you.

Comment: I'm faced with the same problem? Did it work out for you at the end?